# How to we get app download link in Hockey App for iOS

Tags: ios, hockeyapp, in-house-distribution

Basically I was looking for Private Store for in-house App distribution.

I came across Diawi and Hockey app.
Diawi was pretty much strait forward but I got stuck with Hockey as I am not able figure out how to get the download url link over hockey app.. Is it necessary to integrate the hockey SDK Into our project to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering here so that newbies who are new to HockeyApp can add some help from here.

So here it is, Into Hockey app we don't not have a public link to download like in **Diawi** but it works much similar like **TestFlight**.

> **However public link is available over Appcenter for the distribution
>   group created**
>
> The only difference with TestFlight is that you can distribute even on
>   enterprise version over Appcenter

**Step 1:**
 You should install the hockey app Link : [Install hockeyApp](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/configuration) or 
**Alternatively** you can login with Appcenter over your browser and once you get the mail you can click on the download which will prompt to install the mscenter config certificate into your device

**Step 2:**
The app will prompt you to sign up.So Sign up an account.

**Step 3:**
share your mail ID to Device udid with the owner of app at appcenter.

**Step 4:**
 Once the app is uploaded or new version is updated then you would receive a mail or. notification over your device.

**Step 5:**
 Click on download and instal on mail and that's it you will see Install option screen.

HockeyApp is now acquired by Microsoft and therefore you can enjoy the features of **Appcenter** as well.

Link:
[Hockey app became free for developer](https://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2017/12/19/hockeyApp-is-now-free-for-all-developers.html)

Login link [Login into hockey app](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/)

Once you login just drag and drop your IPA into dashboard and it would upload.
Alternatively you can use the hockey desktop app to upload the build through spa or Archive.

Add new device link:  [Adding new device](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/adding-new-ios-devices-to-your-provisioning-profile)

> With iOS ad-hoc provisioning, you will need to add new devices to your provisioning profile by UDID. (You can use more than one Apple Developer Account from the same HockeyApp account, but you can only use one Apple Developer Account per app. You can also have multiple devices associated with one user account, or one device associated with multiple user accounts.)
>
> Apps that qualify to use enterprise provisioning profiles with the Apple Enterprise Developer Program are exempt from needing to import UDIDs into the provisioning profile. (Mixing ad-hoc and enterprise builds in the same app is not supported. You need to split ad-hoc and enterprise builds into two different apps.)

Add beta testers link : [Add beta testers](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-invite-beta-testers#no-account-existing-group-of-testers)

Please add if I miss anything

Thanks